# How to unit test forms in NativeScript?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, nativescript

I'm writing an app with Angular 8 and NativeScript. I am building some forms into my app and I want to write unit tests for the forms.

Here's some code snippets:

register.html

```
    <StackLayout class="input-field">
        <Label text="Client Code"></Label>
        <TextField 
            required 
            class="input" 
            [class.is-invalid]="clientCodeField.invalid && clientCodeField.dirty"
            [(ngModel)]="clientcode" 
            #clientCodeField="ngModel">
        </TextField>
        <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

register.component.spec.ts

```
import { RegisterClientCodeComponent } from './register-client-code.component';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from 'nativescript-angular/forms';

describe('RegisterClientCodeComponent', () => {

    let component: RegisterClientCodeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<RegisterClientCodeComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {

        // refine the test module by declaring the test component
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [NativeScriptFormsModule],
            declarations: [RegisterClientCodeComponent]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisterClientCodeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
    });

    it(' RegisterClientCodeComponent should be defined', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

    it(' RegisterClientCodeComponent should be defined', () => {
        //let email = component.form.controls['email'];
        //expect(email.valid).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

However, in the unit test is says that component doesn't have a 'form' part. How can I write my unit test to check if the form is valid or not?

Comment: Does it work if you wrap your form in a `form`?

Comment: I'm not able to do that. It gives an error unless you know how to do it in NativeScript.

Comment: You seem to be using Template Driven Form but trying to test it as Reactive Form.

Comment: @Manoj I'm completely new to this so can you please advise.

Comment: If you are not familiar with Template Driven vs Reactive Form, please go through official Angular docs. You can directly find the text element and type on it, then trigger change detection to update value on ngModel.

Comment: @Manoj I did go through there but it doesn't say how to write the unit tests.

Comment: I asked you to go through the docs to understand the difference. I have mentioned above how you should be doing the test.

Comment: @Manoj OK I understand the difference now. I think that Reactive Forms are the way to go.